# graphing question that im not able to solve

Tags: graphing-functions

Find the standard form of the equation of the line through (4, 1) that is perpendicular to the line
2x = -3y + 7. What is the x- and y-intercept of the line

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: You can find out an equation of a line with a point and slope.  So how can you find out the slope of the line you want?  You can find the $x$ and $y$ intercepts from the equation.

Comment: If line A has slope $~M \neq 0, ~$ and line B is perpendicular to line A, what have you been taught about the slope of line B, in terms of $~(M) ~$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the slope, m from the equation below:
$$2x=-3y+7$$
$$2x-7=-3y$$
$$-3y=2x-7$$
$$y=-\frac{2}{3}x+\frac{7}{3}$$
$$m=-\frac{2}{3}$$

To find the perpendicular slope, let:
$$m_1=-\frac{2}{3}$$

Use the formula:
$$m_1m_2=-1$$
$$\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)m_2=-1$$
$$m_2=\frac{3}{2}$$

Use the basic formula:
$$y=mx+c$$
$$y=\frac{3}{2}x+c$$

Substitute the coordinate $(4,1)$ to get $c$ value:
$$y=\frac{3}{2}x+c$$
$$1=\frac{3}{2}\left(4\right)+c$$
$$1=6+c$$
$$c=-5$$

Therefore:
$$y=\frac{3}{2}x+c$$
$$y=\frac{3}{2}x-5$$

Reference picture:
[image]